# Django: Get a confirmation when a model is saved to db

Tags: django, model

I have a model called Project. 
On updating this model object, I want to show the corresponding "success" or "failed" message.
Somthing like the following: (this doesnt work since save returns an object not boolen).
Do you know how to know if an object is actually saved ?

views.py

```
 if (project.save()):
            messages.success(request, 'Project was deleted')
 else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Your request could not be processed. Please try again.')
```

Comment: where do you want to use the messages ? Can you please post the full code snippet

Comment: You could do a try / except statement instead.  Then if it doesn't save successfully, you can invoke the except portion of the statement